# How can I convert an ObjectResult<T> to IQueryable<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using entity framework in an asp.net mvc 3.0 application.  I'm using a table-valued function to do a full text search on one of my database tables.  I have set the return type to an object of type Request.  Then I feed the results into an expression builder that does a contains operation on the Requests from a list of entities that the user has access to.  This is the code.

```
List<int> UserEntities = db.UserEntities
                              .Where(x => x.UserID.Equals(usr.ID))
                              .Select(x => x.EntityID).ToList();

var requests = db.SearchRequest(keyword)
    .Where(BuildContainsExpression<Request, int>(x => x.EntityID, UserEntities));

//Expression Builder for Contains SQL functionality
static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
     Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }
    if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }
    ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    // p => valueSelector(p) == values[0] || valueSelector(p) == ...
    if (!values.Any())
    {
        return e => false;
    }
    var equals = values.Select(
            value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(
                                      valueSelector.Body, 
                                      Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
    var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>(
                   (accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

The second line will not build.  The compiler is telling me that the SearchRequest procedure is returning ObjectResult but needs IQueryable.  How to I convert the ObjectResult to IQueryable?

Comment: Can't you just call `AsIQueryable()` ?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was confused because I was looking for a .ToQueryable.  I didn't even think of AsQueryable.  If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the extension method [`Queryable.AsQueryable<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb507003.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
using System.Linq
```

and the extension methods will be available.